# Progress bar for single, long command (not a loop) in R

Tags: r

I can see some very nice progress bars in R, for example using the [progress package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progress/progress.pdf) or `cat()`function

The problem is, these only work with long tasks that are performed *incrementally*, like loops or multiple commands

Is there a way to have a progress bar that doesn't rely on a loop or sequence of operations, and can simply work for a single, long command?

#### Note

If I could somehow start the timed progress bar in progress package ***simultaneously*** with the main operation, that would also solve the issue (but I'm not sure if it's possible?). Here is a timed progress bar for reference

```
library(progress)
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = 100)
for (i in 1:100) {
pb$tick()
Sys.sleep(1 / 100)
}
```

#### Also note

An example of a time consuming (single) command could be as simple as `Sys.sleep(20)`. The actual use case I have is extracting a large JSON object from an API which takes 10 - 30 seconds depending on connection speed etc

Comment: Are you able to extract chunks of this object? Or does it all have to be in one call? Could potentially loop through, adding a progress bar, for each chunk etc...

Comment: @HectorHaffenden that was my initial thought. But it's a primitive API so unfortunately not. Just one JSON glob (2mb) and that's all it does

Comment: A "progress bar" started at the same time as a process simply tells you how much progress the progress bar has made. It doesn't say anything about the progress of the process. For a file download you would have to compare how much has been downloaded to the total file size.